# can we delete slides with multiple range using opentbs?

Tags: opentbs, tinybutstrong

currently we are doing this, which is working fine, but i was trying to delete slide with multiple range

```
 $slides_to_deletea = range(3, $num_slides);   
 $TBS->PlugIn(OPENTBS_DELETE_SLIDES, $slides_to_deletea);
```

can we delete multiple slide from different range

```
$slides_to_deletea = range(3, 5);
$slides_to_deletea = range(8, 12);
```

i tried this https://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php?doc#opentbs_delete_sheets

and also i was wondering if we can merge slides after deleting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can we delete multiple slide from different range

Yes.

Example #1

```
$slides_to_deletea = range(3, 5);  
$TBS->PlugIn(OPENTBS_DELETE_SLIDES, $slides_to_deletea);

// continue to merge as you wish here…

$slides_to_deletea = range(8, 12);
$TBS->PlugIn(OPENTBS_DELETE_SLIDES, $slides_to_deletea);
```

Example #2

```
$slides_to_deletea = range(3, 5);  
$slides_to_deletea = array_merge($slides_to_deletea, range(8, 12));
$TBS->PlugIn(OPENTBS_DELETE_SLIDES, $slides_to_deletea);
```

> and also i was wondering if we can merge slides after deleting?

Yes. When you use OPENTBS_DELETE_SLIDES, slides are only marked to be deleted. And slides (as well as sheets) are actually deleted during the final merging process only. That is when you call *Show()*. This enables you to undo a delete, and also to keep the numbering of slides after a delete, so that you can continue to  drive the merging as you wish using a constant numbering.