OpenTBS/PPTX delete master slides and all associated slides (generated from master slides which are deleted)
How can I delete master slides and all slides depending on these master slides, which should be deleted?
If deleting does not work, perhaps there is a workaround?
E.g.

hiding specific ...
copy specific to a new pptx file ...

I tried to delete master slides this way:
If I do this from the array (see below function I used) that contains the layout subfiles xml data, the powerpoint file gets corrupt and I have to repair it when I open it. Then I see that the deleted master slide has been replaced by an empty (default) one.
$files = $TBS->Plugin(OPENTBS_GET_FILES);

Thanks for any ideas

Have you see this post...? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67386031/can-we-delete-slides-with-multiple-range-using-opentbs

Yes, I have experimented with that. But according to my tests, it only deletes the slides (presentation slides). I am trying to delete the master slides. According to the documentation, there is no parameter with which I can control access to the master: $TBS->PlugIn(OPENTBS_DELETE_SLIDES, $NumOrNames[, $Delete]) Is it possible to access the master slides with the OPENTBS_DELETE_SLIDES plugin?

You can delete slides using:

$TBS->PlugIn(OPENTBS_DELETE_SLIDES, …);

But for now it cannot delete Master Slides (OpenTBS 1.12.1).
And you can hide (or display) slides using:

$TBS->PlugIn(OPENTBS_DISPLAY_SLIDES, …);

OpenTBS has no provided feature for finding slides corresponding to a specific Master Slide, but the following code gives you the list of Slides in the PPTX  and their Layout / Master Slide information.
You can use it to deleted the targeted slides. And leave unused Master Slides remain in the PPTX.
// Establish the list of Layouts an their associated MasterSlides
$layout_lst = array();
$file_master_lst = $TBS->Plugin(OPENTBS_GET_FILES_BY_TYPE, 'slidem');
foreach ($file_master_lst as $file) {
    $name = basename($file); // name of the file
    $rel_file = dirname($file) . '/_rels/' . $name . '.rels'; // path of the corresponding rel file
    $TBS->PlugIn(OPENTBS_SELECT_FILE, $rel_file); // open a read the rel file
    $pattern = '|Target=\"\.\.\/slideLayouts\/([^"]*)|'; // layouts of the master slide
    preg_match_all($pattern, $TBS->Source, $matches);
    foreach ($matches[1] as $m) {
        $layout_lst[$m] = $name;
    }
}

// Establish the list of Slides an their associated MasterSlides and Layouts
$slide_lst  = array();
$file_slide_lst = $TBS->Plugin(OPENTBS_GET_FILES_BY_TYPE, 'slide');
foreach ($file_slide_lst as $file) {
    $name = basename($file); // name of the file
    $rel_file = dirname($file) . '/_rels/' . $name . '.rels'; // path of the corresponding rel file
    $TBS->PlugIn(OPENTBS_SELECT_FILE, $rel_file); // open a read the rel file
    $pattern = '|Target=\"\.\.\/slideLayouts\/([^"]*)|'; // layout of the slide
    preg_match_all($pattern, $TBS->Source, $matches);
    foreach ($matches[1] as $m) {
        $slide_lst[] = array(
            'file_path' =>   $file,
            'file_name' =>   $name,
            'layout' =>      $m,
            'masterSlide' => $layout_lst[$m],
        );
    }
}

var_export($slide_lst);

